# Logout URL performing strange

Tags: logout

When I enter url :

> http://www.example.com/wp-login.php?action=logout

it asks if you want to log out or not ?

why does it happen where I am not logged in as a admin?

If I run this url on any website like

> http://www.example.com/wp-login.php?action=logout

The admin of that site comes to know that somebody logged out, when I just used this url, without admin username and password.

Comment: This behaviour seems to be acceptable to WP developers - see for instance the variation https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22254 marked wontfix.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because of a missing nonce parameter in the URL.

Every WordPress action, including login/logout, validates the nonce first, to make sure the request comes from a known source.

Answer (score 2):

To further Dan's answer, in order to properly form a login or logout link, WordPress provides you two functions;

[wp_login_url()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_url) and [wp_logout_url()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_logout_url) - both of which generate a URL with a nonce for you. There's actually a further helper function, [wp_loginout()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_loginout) which provides a log in link if the user is logged and and a log out link if the user is logged in.

If you look on the screen you're presented if you just type in example.com/wp-login.php?action=logout you'll see that it generates a link that includes a nonce.