# Logout using link (without nonce)

Tags: logout

This question comes from an absolute non-coder - and has been asked in various forms several times befor (e.g. [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/175395/logout-url-performing-strange/175464#175464)).

To logout properly the URL that triggers it needs a nonce as e.g.:

> http://xyz/wp-login.php?action=logout&redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.spiegel.de&_wpnonce=d9d1a28ef2

We can get the nonce as described in the codex. BUT: what if I have to trigger a logout is by using a URL. More precisely: my CiviCRM plugin has forms that people can fill out and once completed let the user redirect somewhere else -> e.g. log out and go to another page. I can copy/paste the redirct URL in a form such as

> http://xyz/wp-login.php?action=logout&redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.spiegel.de

-> how do I get the nonce where it is supposed to go - or are there alternatives???

Cheers!

Comment: Nonces are time-based per-user - the only way to get them is through WordPress. You'd either have to "hook" into the CiviCRM and work out how you can dynamically pass it the redirect URL (as opposed to copy/pasting it in a setting), or remove nonce checking from the logout process (not recommended)

Comment: Thought so - thanks (will close the question then). Just out of interest - even though it's not recommended - how would I go about removing nonce-checking? Cheers!

Comment: I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 2):

**This will disable nonce checking for logging out** - on your head be it:

```
add_action( 'login_form_logout', function () {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    wp_logout();

    if ( ! empty( $_REQUEST['redirect_to'] ) ) {
        $redirect_to = $requested_redirect_to = $_REQUEST['redirect_to'];
    } else {
        $redirect_to = 'wp-login.php?loggedout=true';
        $requested_redirect_to = '';
    }

    /**
     * Filters the log out redirect URL.
     *
     * @since 4.2.0
     *
     * @param string  $redirect_to           The redirect destination URL.
     * @param string  $requested_redirect_to The requested redirect destination URL passed as a parameter.
     * @param WP_User $user                  The WP_User object for the user that's logging out.
     */
    $redirect_to = apply_filters( 'logout_redirect', $redirect_to, $requested_redirect_to, $user );
    wp_safe_redirect( $redirect_to );
    exit;
});
```

Comment: I just replaced $redirect_to = '/'; to redirect to homepage after logout.